# how can i use the variable outside the onDataChange Method of firebase?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

[check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkEYw.png)

I want use variable of onDataChange method to use outside of the method can someone help me through this?

Comment: There is no way you can `mCity` outside the callback. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).

Comment: i did with shared preference is this a good idea or not?

Comment: SharedPrefs doesn't persist across app uninstalls. If that's not a problem, then you can go ahead with it, otherwise save the data in the Cloud.